# What would be the best way to explain "there, they're and their"?

Tags: singular-they

I was wondering what the best way to explain the difference and how to use the words "they're, their and there" properly because I always get them mixed up.

Comment: This question is better suited to ell.stackexchange

Answer (score 3):

*They're* is the easiest if you remember that it's a contraction of "they are".

If something isn't *here* then it is *there*. Note that *there* contains *here*.

Answer (score 0):

> Words that sound the same but have different meanings (and sometimes
>   spelling) are called homophones. Therefore, [they're, their and there](http://www.theretheyretheir.com/)
>   are **[Homophones](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/homophone?family=homophones)**.

**[Their](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/there_their_theyre.htm)** (plural) is a possessive adjective which is used before a noun.

•*Their* house is big.

....and used to describe something as belong to them.

•The children put *their* books in *their* school bags.

If the word means "belonging to them," use their.

**They’re** is a contraction of they are.
e.g. They’re happy = They are happy

It is often followed by the present participle (verb form ending in -ing).

•They’re singing loudly.

**There** has several different uses.

**Adverb** that means the opposite of "here"

- He’s over there.
- Stop right there.

**Pronoun** that introduces a noun or clause.

- There is something strange going on.
- Is there a phone?

**Adjective** that emphasizes which person.

- That guy there seems to be in trouble.

**Noun** that means "that place."

- From there, we drove to Boston.
- I’m not going in there.